# Puppeteer blocking variables inside functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, discord, puppeteer

I recently made a quick web scraper using puppeteer as it targets a JS website and want it to send the output that i get inside my console into discord. The thing is that I always get e.g price not defined or so when the script tries to send the web hook onto discord. Thank you all for your help in advance here is my code if someone can help me out please. I mean where should I put my const embed in order for it to work properly.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');

 
// add stealth plugin and use defaults (all evasion techniques)
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const { Webhook, MessageBuilder } = require('discord-webhook-node');
const hook = new Webhook("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/733332015654371361/9VGAVW-BNlf3G4j3L6GhAIDni17yNIVf9gfmf_TNTQafP40LqYvRwhaYZzL_b58kpkkl");

const url = "https://www.asos.com/fr/nike/nike-air-max-270-baskets-triple-noir-ah8050-005/prd/12490103?clr=noir-triple&colourwayid=16391201&SearchQuery=nike air max 270";
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());


async function ConfigureBrowser(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }); // for test disable the headlels mode,
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 926 });
    await page.goto(url,{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
    return page;
};

async function Scrape(page) {
    // await page.reload();
    console.log("start evaluate javascript")
    /** @type {string[]} */
    var productINFO = await page.evaluate(()=>{
        var div = document.querySelectorAll('.core-product-container');
        console.log(div) // console.log inside evaluate, will show on browser console not on node console
        
        const productnames = [] 
        div.forEach(element => { 
            var titleelem = element.querySelector('#aside-content > div.product-hero > h1');
            if(titleelem != null){
                productnames.push(titleelem.textContent.trim());
            } //#aside-content > div.product-hero > h1
        });

        const productprice = [] 
        div.forEach(element => { 
            var price = element.querySelector('[class="current-price"]');
            if(price != null){
                productprice.push(price.textContent.trim());
            }
        });

        const productsizes = [] 
        div.forEach(element => { 
            var sizes = element.querySelector('[data-id="sizeSelect"]');
            if(sizes != null){
                productsizes.push(sizes.textContent.trim());
            }
            // productsizes.forEach()
        })
        
        
        return [productnames, productprice, productsizes]
        

    })


    return productINFO;
    

//     const embed = new MessageBuilder()
// .setTitle(productnames)
// .setURL(url)
// .addField('Prix', productprice, true)
// .addField('sizes', productsizes, true)
// .setColor(8008905)
//                     // .setThumbnail({image})
// .setDescription('Checked')
//                         //.setImage(image)
// .setFooter('', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/720763827658162260/730786942316183603/image0.jpg')
// hook.send(embed);
    discoord(productINFO);
    console.log(productINFO);
    //browser.close()
} ;



async function Monitor() {
   let page = await ConfigureBrowser();
   await Scrape(page);
  // console.log(productINFO);
}

Monitor();
```

Comment: Web scraping and discord are two different things. If the web scraper is the part that isn't working, I recommend stripping out the parts that do work to show a [mcve] of the problem. Which data from the website you're scraping do you need exactly? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast reply, my web scraper is working normally, i prints its output into my console, the problem is to send the data to a web hook on discord.

Comment: OK, great--thanks. Then you can simply hardcode that data that the webscraper is giving as normal variables so that people can focus on the discord problem without confusing distractions. I'd remove the [tag:puppeteer] and [tag:web-scraping] tags which will give you a better chance of getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: The thing is that it might be a problem within the function as puppeteer seems to lock the variables inside Scrape(). I alway get either productrice undefined or so. Any advises ?